# How to set property in jsp in Struts-1

Tags: java, jsp, struts-1

I am very new to Struts, I am using a jsp and Action class

In JSP:

```
<bean:define id="fromdtm1" name="scheduleWorkmenForm"   property="value(fromdtm)"/>
<bean:define id="todtm1" name="scheduleWorkmenForm" property="value(todtm)"/>
<bean:define id="selectedIds" name="scheduleWorkmenForm" property="valueAsStringArray(selectedIds)"/>
```

so here i am using 3 properties from date, todate, and selected ids, where first two are string values and third one is a `String` Array.

Action class:

```
String fromDtm = (String)data.getValue("fromdtm");
String toDtm = (String)data.getValue("todtm");
String ids[] = (String[])(String[])data.getValue("selectedIds");
```

here the problem is every time i click search button , I can observe from ,to dates are coming as which i have selected, but selected ids are coming as null. Please let me know what the mistake is.

Comment: Are you using Struts or Struts2. Please share the Jsp code also.

Comment: I am using struts 1.x

Comment: I don't understand; you want them in the form submission? How are you adding them to the form?